# Input file redirection is causing errors in output

Tags: c, file, unix, gcc

If I type this out as input, I get results. If I pass the same through a file, it prints strange values. What is happening?

This is the correct output. Simple L to R evaluation. It stops inputs on 1000 and prints results

```
$ ./bkp2 
P(x)= x^2 + 4*x - 3
3
4
-1
1000
P(3)=36
P(4)=77
P(-1)=-8
```

This is my input file with the exact parameters

```
$ cat a.in
P(x) = x^2 + 4*x – 3
3
4
-1
1000
```

However, when I run this, disaster happens!

```
$ cc -c bkp2.c 
$ cc -o bkp2 bkp2.o -lm
$ ./bkp2 < a.in
P(3)=117
P(4)=240
P(-1)=-15
```

Please help

Comment: Is there some code too?

Comment: Code is really long. But it works for all inputs as long as they are on the terminal. Basically an evaluator.

Comment: @Deduplicator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838942/garbage-values-are-getting-assigned

Comment: It'd still be worth seeing it, both the screen and file output at least.

Comment: How do you parse the end of a line? File might contain `\n` whole hitting return poduces a `\r`.

Comment: Have you set breakpoints on the file reads to ensure they're correct going into the evaluator; that'd be the first step.

Comment: In the link you provided to the code, it looks as if you marked that question (which has similarities to this one) as answered.  A little debugging on your part will yield what you need.

Comment: `P(x)= x^2 + 4*x - 3` != `P(x) = x^2 + 4*x – 3` : Is different from the form of expression that you are thinking perhaps.